# Set hidden data to uitableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I searched a bit here and on google, but I couldn't really find unearthing that I could clearly understand. Basically what I'd like to do is display a list of names, then when clicking on the table add the ID of those names to another array, along with their ID. The solution I'm working on at the moment is based on nested `NSMutableArrays` but I don't know if that's the best thing to do. I think it would be ideal to have another "field" to write on in the cell (by field I mean something like `cell.text`) so that I could store my hidden value.

Is there a way to do so?!

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking: you have a tableview with data, and if a field is touched you want to add some data of that field to an array - where is the problem?

Comment: I think the best approach is to have your array populated with custom objects with any properties that you need. One of the properties would be "name", and you can display that with something like obj.name, but you can have as many other properties as you want, and either display them or not.

Comment: You should not store data in a UITableViewCell.  Any data should be stored in the data source.

Comment: My standard layout for the data source is an NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary objects, one for each row. Data items can be easily added to the dictionary at any time.  (For a TableView with multiple sections I use an array of arrays of dictionaries.)

Comment: Remember that cells are removed from the view and "recycled" as the view is scrolled, so your "hidden value" could disappear, then reappear in a different row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your thinking. Cocoa strongly follows the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern, and you should learn to think that way.

In MVC, the model is the part of the program that stores your data. The View is what displays information to the user and interacts with the user.

The controller is the brains that serves as the control logic and feeds data back and forth between the model and the view.

In UIKit, objects with View in their name are view objects, and objects with controller in their name are controller objects. As a general rule the model object is up to you, as its application specific.

A table view is a view object. It doesn't store information, it presents it to the user and/or collects it from the user.

An array usually is the best choice for storing the data that gets presented in a table view. If you have a table view with multiple sections and multiple rows in each section than an array for each section, containing an array with data for each row is a good choice. Unless you have a sectioned table view forget about that however. It'll just confuse you.

For a "flat" table view with only one section, a single array is usually what you want.

How you store the data that you display in a cell is a design question. One easy answer is to use a dictionary for the data in each cell. So you wind up with an array of dictionaries.

If you're comfortable creating custom objects the a custom data storage object makes your code a little cleaner. However, you will probably want to implement the NSCoding protocol in your data objects so you can save them to disk easily.

Using an array to store the data for a cell is NOT a very good choice, because arrays use numeric indexes for their data. You might have a name that you want to display in your cell, and an image, and an employee ID, and a salary, and a few other things. What numeric indexes should you use for those values? Not clear. Now, if you use a dictionary, you can use meaningful keys:

```
cellData[@"name"]
cellData[@"imageName"]
```

or better yet, define constants for your keys:

```
#define kNameKey @"name"
#define kImageNameKey @"imageName"
```

then

```
cellData[kNameKey]
cellData[kImageNameKey]
```

That way you don't risk mis-typing the key string somewhere and introducing a bug that you have to go figure out.

If you're a beginner you might want to start out with an array of dictionaries. After you've used that approach for a while you might decide to migrate to custom data objects.

Let's assume we're using a dictionary to store the data for each cell from now on.

Now, to your question. It's perfectly ok to store more information in the dictionary for each cell than you display at any one time. The data isn't really hidden, it's just not (yet) displayed. Then, if the user takes an action that means you want to expose additional data, tell the table view to reload that cell. You might want to keep an array of info about the status of each cell (e.g. a bool that tells if the table view should display the salary info for each entry in your data array.) When the user does something that changes the info you want to display, change the appropriate setting in that index in the display status array and tell the table view to reload that cell. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you would check the display status array for what to display for that cell, then fetch the appropriate data and install it into the cell (and clear out fields that should not be shown, since they might be left over from the last time the cell was used.)

If you have an array of dictionaries, then your cellForRowAtIndexPath method might look up the attributes of an entry like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
  NSDictionary *rowData = dataArray[row]
  NSString *name = rowData[kNameKey];
  NSString *imageName = rowData[kImageNameKey];
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, my only problem Is how I can select the object of the array I used to populate the Table. Let's say in the table I'm displaying that "name field" of the NSDictionary in the nested NSArray, how can I get to the "ID field" of the name I selected through the table? That was why I asked the question in the first place, it seemed more convenient to me to store the IS data alongside the name data within the same cell

Comment: See my edit. Trying to store data in table view cells is a bad, bad idea. Trust me on this. That road leads to tears and sorrow. Cells get used, recycled, and reused constantly, and the same cell will display data for a different index in your array of data 5 seconds later. If you store data in a cell it will wind up being displayed in the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

Think more object-oriented, it'll make things like this a lot easier.

Make a class called `Person` with two properties: `name` and `ID`. Subclass UITableViewCell to take a list of `Person`, for which each name will be displayed.  When the cell is clicked, add each `Person` to the appropriate location.

Here is a link for a tutorial on how to subclass youor own custom table view cell:
http://www.pumpmybicep.com/2014/07/21/designing-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-interface-builder/

As for the Person class, create a new class of type NSObject called Person.  In Person.h, add the following:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int *ID;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name ID:(int)ID;
```

And in Person.m, add the following:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name ID:(int)ID {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = name;
        self.ID = ID;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now you can transfer data using `Person`.

Initialize:

```
Person *myPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithName:myName ID:1];
```

Get:

```
customCell.text = myPerson.name;
```

Transfer ID:

```
[clickedIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:myPerson.ID]];
```

Comment: This would be a nice feat, if only I knew how to do it! Do you have any other hint or a link to a guide - tutorial?

Answer (score -2):

You could subclass a UITableViewCell and add an extra property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *hidden;
```

for example. Then:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomUITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.text = @"Name";
    cell.hidden = @"ID";
    return cell;
}
```

That's how to do what you've asked, however it seems an odd request so you may want to consider if that's really the best way of achieving what you're trying to do. I'm not clear from your question what you've tried though.

Comment: No. Not a good idea at all. Don't store data in a cell. Remember that the user can scroll any given cell off the screen, and that cell will get recycled to display a different entry in the data.  If you then scroll back, a completely different cell will likely be used to display that index in the table, but the info about the hidden state of a field will be lost. See my answer for a better suggestion.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that the cells are being reused :( but thanks for the answer Nilskilz!

Comment: yea, that slipped my mind too. You could just init the cells and not reuse them, but that's not good either. Like I said, you technically could do this, but I agree it's not a good idea.

Comment: Basically what I have to do is get the ID propriety of a list of names. I know exactly how to populate the table with the names. I know how can I get out the name when I select the cell. But I have no idea how can I retrieve the ID of a cell I selected. I could search for the name in the array, but what if have 2 names that are the same?